# Transferring data from one excel sheet to another

Tags: excel

I will preface this by saying I have not much experience with excel.

I'm looking to see if there is a way to input data into one sheet and simultaneously transfer the data to different cells in another. The sheets are not formatted the same. The sheets are used for tracking shipment data. Sheet 1 is for a shipping manifest of contents and the second is used as a master tracker to tell what items were shipped when, quantities, truck #, location # etc.

Is this possible given they're of different formatting?

Comment: VBA or some formula... hard to specify here exactly given the vague description.

Comment: You can use VLOOKUP formula if you want to tract some specific item on sheet2 while getting data from sheet1